# Why could create socketchannels more than max open files?

Tags: linux, sockets, nio

In linux Socket also is a  file, so if exist too many sockets at a time and  more than max open files, it will throw  below exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:423)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:416)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:104)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60)
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:142)
```

Till now I could understand, but I'm a little confused with below phenomenon. 
I executed below command in terminal to find max open file number:

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
```

But actually I created about 4091 sockets(SocketChannel) by below code:

```
while(true) {   
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //...
            try {
                SocketChannel scChannel = SocketChannel.open();
                scChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port));
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                scChannel.read(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //...
            }                   
        }
    }).start(); 
}
```

and from console I knew until it created 4091 socketChannel, then it threw above exception:

```
Start client 4091
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
```

4091 is more than 1024, so why is so? The result from ulimit is not real number of max open files?

Comment: Your Java runtime or one of the libraries might be adjucting ulimit. Check it from the program itself.

Comment: Thanks！ You are right. Jvm indeed interfered.

Answer (score 1):

According to n.m.'s advice, I checked if jvm changed ulimit. And I found jvm indeed does something. I executed ulimit command by java code as below:

```
ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("sh","-c","ulimit -n");
Process p = pBuilder.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line!=null){
    System.out.println(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

the output is 4096--it is different from terminal output.
But I don't know how and when and where jvm changed the ulimit value.